# HS commands not working from the command line

Tags: command-line-interface, hubspot

Just recently enrolled in the HubSpot Developer course and can't seem to get hs commands to work from my terminal. Noticed this error message when I first installed the hs package and wondering if it has something to do with it.

```
@hubspot/cli update check failed
Try running with sudo or get access
to the local update config store via
chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/alexandraholden/.config
```

Otherwise, I just get errors like this:

```
zsh: command not found: hs
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.